# How can I improve this Caesar encryption?

Tags: c#, caesar-cipher

I have the following method which encrypts a english text, given the plain text and the desired key:

```
/// <summary>
/// Encrypts english plain text using user defined key. Range for the key is from -25 to 25.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="plainText"></param>
/// <param name="keyValue"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string encryptTextEng(String plainText,int keyValue)
{
    string encText = "";
    char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++)
    {
        if (plainText[i].ToString() == " ")
        {
            encText += " ";
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.Length; j++)
        {
            if (String.Equals(alphabet[j].ToString(), plainText[i].ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                try
                {
                    encText += alphabet[j + keyValue];
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (j + keyValue > 26)
                    {
                        encText += alphabet[j + keyValue - 26];
                    }
                    else if (j + keyValue < 0)
                    {
                        encText += alphabet[j + keyValue + 26];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return encText;
}
```

What are good programming practices I am missing here? Also I am not sure about the try/catch part I guess there are better ways to do it? Would it be a good idea to add a switch case which checks if the char it is currently reading is a punctuation character?

Comment: Often, when I see a `for-if` or a `foreach-if`, I assume there's a missing `Where`. When I see nested `for`s, I assume there's a missing `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct in suspecting that the try/catch is not necessary. Generally speaking, Caesar ciphers are implemented using [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). We can determine if a character is alphabetical by simply checking if `alphabet` contains that character; anything else (whitespace, digits, punctuation, etc.) can just be copied as-is, so neither the second for loop nor the proposed switch are necessary either. Here's an example of how you could simplify your code:

```
public static string encryptTextEng(string plainText, int keyValue)
{
    string encText = "";
    char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();

    foreach (char c in plainText.ToUpper())
    {
        if (alphabet.Contains(c))
        {
            encText += alphabet[Mod((Array.IndexOf(alphabet, c) + keyValue), 26)];
        }
        else
        {
            encText += c;
        }
    }

    return encText;
}

private static int Mod(int dividend, int divisor)
{
    int remainder = dividend % divisor;
    return remainder < 0 ? remainder + divisor : remainder;
}
```

I threw the Mod method in there because the modulo operator [does not work as you might expect with negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain).

---

As mentioned by Bruno in the comments below, a more performant way of checking if the current character is in `alphabet` and getting the index of that character would be:

```
foreach (char c in plainText.ToUpper())
{
    int idx = c - 'A';
    if (idx >= 0 && idx < alphabet.Length)
    {
        encText += alphabet[Mod(idx + keyValue, 26)];
    }
    else
    {
        encText += c;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you could simplify the mod operation by using `return (Dividend + Divisor) % Divisor;`

Comment: Good point. I'll change that now.

Comment: You can also substitute your alphabet.Contains O(n) for c - 'A' < alphabet.Length O(1). You can also use that value as a indexer so you don't have to use IndexOf. http://pastebin.com/CPDWh19J

Comment: @Simon Actually it just occurred to me that `return (Dividend + Divisor) % Divisor;` doesn't work quite the same way as the original implementation and can still end up returning a negative number

Comment: Crap, you're right! For the general case it can. Although for this specific case, I believe it won't.

Comment: @Bruno yep, that works just as well, if not better. I'm not convinced that there's significant performance impact from using those array methods in this case given how small `alphabet` is but I agree in principle that it's probably a better way of doing things.

Comment: You have a `)` too much in your `Mod` call in the second version - Should be `Mod(idx + keyValue, 26)`. Also if you make `keyValue` an `unsigned int` then you can get rid of the `Mod` method entirely because then you know `idx + keyValue` will never be negative. Also standard naming conventions for method parameters is `camelCase`

Comment: @ChrisWue: fixed the bracket and casing (I just copied Bruno's code so I didn't catch the stray bracket). Using unsigned would also work but the OP's code indicates that he/she wants to be able to input negative values.

Comment: Sorry for that ) <.< .

Comment: What are the numbers in front of every char in the char array?

Comment: Which part are you talking about, @bodycountPP?

Comment: You should consider using `ToUpperInvariant()` instead of `ToUpper()`. Otherwise, [your code won't work in Turkey](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html).

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to have 2 arrays, one with chars to map from and one with chars to map to.

Then a simple look up, something like this, is all that is necessary

```
char[] mapFrom = "ABC".ToCharArray();
char[] mapTo   = "LMN".ToCharArray();

mapTo[Array.IndexOf(mapFrom, ch)]
```

Advantages include a fast look-up, simple easy to understand code, and the fact that the 2 array could be either hard-coded or generated using the desired algorithm (only once).